# Почему при переподключении jquery может отвалиться myajax?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ajax

До этого все работало и jquery был подключен через функшенс

```
function my_scripts() { 
?>  
<script type="f71ad2114b19723ebddd10ca-text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<?php
}
```

jquery был переподключен там же

```
function my_scripts() {  
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь, если заглянуть в код страницы, то myajax не подключается. Что могло послужить этому?
Вот так подключен myajax

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 2000);
function myajax_data(){
  wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'myajax',
    array(
      'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил переместив jquery в футер

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-js' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', false, null, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js' );
```